# Why there is no Spark connector for Databricks?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, connector

I would like to read data in Databricks with Spark outside of Databricks. But looks like there is no spark connector for Databricks available. [Snowflake Connector for Spark](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector.html) is an example, I am looking for something similar for Databricks.

Answer (score 0):

May I know what you mean by connectors ?
Databricks by itself will have the spark clusters running in it.

You can attach notebooks or run a spark job on top of it.
https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/index.html

If you want to connect your local machine to databricks cluster and do development - you can try below databricks connect.
https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html

Comment: I know Databricks has spark clusters. For my use case, I need to read data in Databricks with Spark cluster outside of Databricks. I am looking for something similar to [Snowflake Connector for Spark](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector.html).

Comment: Databricks connect still runs in job in databricks cluster, that's not what I need.